# Mutiplication powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to make a multiplication table from 1 to 12 with the number the users input. This is the code i write
`your text`$nombre = Read-Host "Entrez un nombre :"

```
Write-Host "Table de multiplication de $nombre :"
for ($i=1; $i -le 12; $i++) {
$resultat = $nombre * $i
Write-Host "$nombre x $i = $resultat"}
```

but instead of multiplication it put every number side by side example if u do 2 * 2 it give me 22 instead of the multiplication answer.

```
Write-Host "Table de multiplication de $nombre :"
for ($i=1; $i -le 12; $i++) {
$resultat = $nombre * $i
Write-Host "$nombre x $i = $resultat"}

Entrez un nombre : : 2
Table de multiplication de 2 :
2 x 1 = 2
2 x 2 = 22
2 x 3 = 222
2 x 4 = 2222
2 x 5 = 22222
2 x 6 = 222222
2 x 7 = 2222222
2 x 8 = 22222222
2 x 9 = 222222222
2 x 10 = 2222222222
2 x 11 = 22222222222
2 x 12 = 222222222222
```

Answer (score 1):

See [about_Arithmetic_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-7.2#long-description),
`*` can multiply numbers or copy strings and arrays the specified number of times.

The result from [`Read-Host` is always a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-7.3#outputs), which is why you're seeing duplication of the strings containing a number instead the actual arithmetic operation.

Solving this is quite simple, just need to convert the output from `Read-Host` to an integer:

```
[int] $nombre = Read-Host 'Entrez un nombre'
Write-Host "Table de multiplication de $nombre :"
for ($i=1; $i -le 12; $i++) {
   $resultat = $nombre * $i
   Write-Host "$nombre x $i = $resultat"
}
```